# MAAS bootstrap ssh port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh, juju, maas, debootstrap

I am trying to bootstrap my first node but I am receiving:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.30.41 port 22: Connection refused
```

I configured an ssh key in MAAS preferences and I also tried the following but there was no change:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
sudo ufw disable
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply start or deploy that node from MAAS without using Juju? I would start there first, and make sure you have imported your key in the MAAS user settings.